# Correlation functions of exactly solvable 1D quantum models

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, spin-models, integrable-systems

Quantum 1d spin-1/2 transverse Ising and XY models are both related to 2d classical Ising model. Are there any known simple explicit relations between correlation functions of this models? Something like one equals square root of another. I was not able to find answer myself.